# findNavController is missing and not working

Tags: android, kotlin

i was doing this https://youtu.be/GOpeBbfyb6s?t=1405 with navigation arch but i cant type it.findNavController it is showing red

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    lgnbtn.setOnClickListener {
        val nameBundle = Bundle()
        nameBundle.putString("name",idfield.text.toString())
        it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.mainFragment, nameBundle)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add to build.gradle `implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [Declaring Navigation dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#declaring_dependencies), you must use the `-ktx` versions of the dependencies to use Kotlin extensions, such as the `findNavController()` extension for `View`.

Therefore, replace any dependencies on `navigation-fragment` with `navigation-fragment-ktx` and similarly for `navigation-ui` with `navigation-ui-ktx`.

Comment: If this helped answer your question, make sure to accept the answer to remove the question for the queue of unanswered questions. Best of luck going forward!